# Do I need to explicitly call a destructor here?

Tags: c++, c++11

I've got an optional-like type (can't use optional because it's C++17):

```
template <typename T>
struct maybe {
    maybe()        : valid_(false) {}
    maybe(T value) : valid_(true)  { new (&value_) T(value); }

    // destructor
    ~maybe() {
        if (valid_) {
            value_.~T();
        }
    }

    // move value out of maybe
    operator T&&() && {
        valid_ = false;
        return std::move(value());
    }

    // explicit validity 
    explicit operator bool() const {
        return valid_;
    }

    T& value() {
        if (!valid_) {
            throw std::runtime_error("boom");
        }
        return value_;
    }

private:
    union {
        T value_;
    };
    bool valid_;
};
```

I'm curious in the `operator T&&` if it's improper to just move the value out, since the destructor will no longer do it.  It seems like I would need to move the value to a temporary, destruct my storage, and then return.  Which way is correct?

Comment: `valid_` should probably be left `true`. By returning an rvalue reference to your value, it means that the value may shortly become moved-from but it's still an instance of `T`. Since there's no easy way to detect when it actually  gets moved from, the simple solution would be to not touch `valid_` and let the moved-from instance be destroyed normally by your destructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no need to call destructor manually. Move is only used to invoke overload taking an rvalue reference. If calling code does nothing with function result then this would be noop. Even if calling code does actually mess with the value is supposed to stay in some valid (but unspecified) state and still needs to be properly destructed (and this will happen when `maybe` object is destructed).

Comment: That makes sense, thank you.  I'll elide invalidating it when the operator's called, and just document that's it undefined to access a maybe after std::move()-ing from it.

Comment: @SeanMcAllister For your operator to be called, you need to be operating on an rvalue reference of `maybe` already. Afterwards, the user should already be in a situation where they can't really expect their `maybe` to hold a value anymore.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux That why `valid_` is set to `false`, isn't it?

Comment: @VTT `valid_` seems to indicate whether or not `value_` contains an object. A moved-from object is still an object. It seems to me like it's still valid, as far as the use of `valid_` is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

```
// move value out of maybe
operator T&&() && {
    valid_ = false;
    return std::move(value());
}
```

Your problem is `valid_ = false;` -- that line is wrong.

Your class has the invariant that either it contains a value and `valid_` is `true`, or it doesn't contain a value and `valid_` is `false`.

Your `operator T&&()&&` violates this invariant.

Options include:

```
// move value out of maybe
operator T&&() && {
    return std::move(value());
}
```

or

```
// move value out of maybe
operator T() && {
  T tmp = std::move(value());
  value().~T();
  valid_ = false;
  return tmp;
}
```

`std::optional` uses the first one, the second one is also possible.

As an aside:

```
maybe(T value) : valid_(true)  { new (&value_) T(value); }
```

needs a `std::move`:

```
maybe(T value) : valid_(true)  { new (&value_) T(std::move(value)); }
```

and some other defensive measures:

```
maybe(T value) : valid_(true)  { ::new ((void*)&value_) T(std::move(value)); }
```

to deal with `operator new` overloading.

Next, you need to deal with throwing constructors:

```
maybe(T value) : maybe()  {
  ::new ((void*)&value_) T(std::move(value));
  valid_ = true;
}
```

you should go even further

```
template<class...Args>
void emplace(Args&&...args) {
  if (*this)
    clear();
  ::new( (void*)&value_ ) T( std::forward<Args>(args)... );
  valid_ = true;
}
void clear() {
  if (*this)
  {
    valid_ = false; // set false first in case ~T throws
    value().~T(); 
  }
}
```

now we:

```
maybe(T value)
: maybe() {
  emplace( std::move(value ) );
}

~maybe()
{
  clear();
}
```

and only manually fiddle with the lifetime of `value_` and `valid_` inside `emplace()` and `clear()`.

We should also have valid `noexcept` values:

```
template<class...Args>
void emplace(Args&&...args)
  noexcept(
    noexcept( T( std::forward<Args>(args)... )
    && noexcept( std::declval<maybe&>().clear() )
 )
{
  if (*this)
    clear();
  ::new( (void*)&value_ ) T( std::forward<Args>(args)... );
  valid_ = true;
}
void clear() noexcept(noexcept( std::declval<T&>().~T() ) ) {
  if (*this)
  {
    valid_ = false; // set false first in case ~T throws
    value().~T(); 
  }
}
```

now we:

```
maybe(T value)
  noexcept( noexcept( std::declval<maybe&>().emplace( std::declval<T&&>() ) ) )
: maybe() {
  emplace( std::move(value ) );
}

~maybe()
  noexcept( noexcept( std::declval<maybe&>().clear() ) )
{
  clear();
}
```

Comment: This was a stripped down example ( I don't actually build from a value, I take a const T&), but the thoughts on exceptions and such were very useful, thank you.